# Enable conection bridge in centOS 6.1

Tags: centos, vmware, bridge

It used a vm with centos 6 in bridge, without any problem. But today, when starting vm, it is stated that there is no connectivity to the network.

I have the following error message: 'Bonding, bridging, and VLANS are disabled in NetWorkManager.'

[image]

My ifcfg_bridge_conection:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The version of NetworkManager in CentOS 6 doesn’t support bridging. Use `NM_CONTROLLED=no`in the ifcfg file to make sure the “network” service manages it instead. Also, [read more about this limitation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/s2-networkscripts-interfaces_network-bridge) in the Redhat docs.

Comment: Also, I really hope that’s a typo and you meant CentOS 6.10.

Comment: I define in ifcfg-lo it? https://prntscr.com/n60npr

Comment: No, the bridge definition file.

Comment: Result 'ifconfig:' http://prntscr.com/n60v08 - Configuration bridge: http://prntscr.com/n60vtt

I use wi-fi connection. Is this 'Link encap: Ethernet' correct on bridge?